# Angular cli 7.1.4 extracted styles.css file unexpected character

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass, angular-cli

I am using Angular cli 7.1.4 and bootstrap 4.2.1 in my angular application.

Angular.json file:

```
"architect": {
   "build": {
      "options": {
          "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",              
          "src/styles.scss"
        ]
      },
     "configurations": {
        "localrelease": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.localrelease.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            }
          ]
        }
   }
}
```

styles.scss:

```
// Theme variables, must be included before the libraries to allow 
   overriding defaults   

// 3rd party libraries
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

The problem is when I build the project using the 'ng build --configuration localrelease', browser console outputs the following error:

```
styles.9d1b9f2acfda72d82b52.css:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

styles.css:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v4.2.1 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2018 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2018 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT         
  */:root{--blue:#007bff;--indigo:#6610f2;--purple:#6f42c1;--pink:#e83e8
```

Apparently the problem derives from a 3rd party library(bootstrap). Can anyone adddress what I am doing wrong? It would be much appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

```
"styles": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",              
      "src/styles.scss"
    ]
```

when you do `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`, it gets added again. Try removing one of these.